# File not found in XCode 5 with frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode5

Have searched SO and i'm still having this issue.

XCode 5.0.1. I'm trying to add the StoreKit framework just as I would with any standard framework. Added in Build Phases link binaries. But as soon as I `#import "<StoreKit/StoreKit.h>"`I get a Lexical Preprocessor Issue file not found error?

So far I have added & removed framework. Cleaned project. Restarted XCode but still nothing gets rid of the error?

Always Search User Paths is set to YES. Paths in User Header Search Paths is set to the path to my project.

Comment: `#import "<StoreKit/StoreKit.h>"`: The double quote are a typo error?

Comment: Oh man yes school boy error. Thanks.

Comment: So was that the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm as Larme stated, I totally missed the fact that I had typed `#import "<StoreKit/StoreKit.h>"` instead of `#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>`. Without the quotation marks.

Totally my error should have known better! Jon hope this helps.